# domUs hang in start up, Debian Lenny

Tags: debian, xen

My server box has a hardware problem, so I unracked it and brought it home.  While it was home, I figured it was time to upgrade from Etch to Lenny.  Unfortunately, now that I've done so, all my domUs hang while starting up.  I even tried making a new domU using

```
xen-create-image --lvm xen-space --hostname=test1 --size=8Gb --dist=lenny --memory=512M --dhcp
```

and when it starts up, it hangs in startup as well.  The last message on the console is

```
Starting periodic command scheduler: crond.
```

The last thing in xend.log is

```
INFO (XendDomain:1165) Domain test1 (7) unpaused.
[ 5526.429198] blkback: ring-ref 8, event-channel 8, protcol 1 (x86_32-abi)
[ 5526.441788] blkback: ring-ref 9, event-channel 9, protcol 1 (x86_32-abi)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's not hung, it just isn't outputting anything to the console.  you need to add the following to your kernel command line

```
console=hvc0 xencons=tty
```

you can then fix it by editing inittab I believe...

http://wiki.debian.org/Xen#Nologinpromptwhenusing.60xmconsole.60

Comment: Am I misreading that?  I thought it was saying that hvc0 was for the serial console, not for the console you get when you do "xm console"?

Comment: I have no idea what the difference is, if there even is one.. all I know is that specifying hvc0 fixes the problem :-)

Comment: Yeah, the wiki wasn't too clear, but it turns out that I had to change the `1:...*getty tty` on all the domUs as well, as well as installing udev on all of them so that ssh works.

Comment: ah yeah... the getty stuff is for the domU, you shouldn't have to touch the dom0 unless that was having problems too.